# ElasticSearch range query in a paragraph

Tags: java, elasticsearch, range

I have a field called Description which is a text field and has data like:

> This is a good thing for versions before 3.2 but bad for 3.5 and later

I want to run range query on this type of text. I know that for a field containing only Dates/Age(Numbers) or even String Ids, we can use queries like

```
{
    "query": {
        "range" : {
            "age" : {
                "gte" : 10,
                "lte" : 20,
                "boost" : 2.0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But i have a mixed field like mentioned above and I need to perform range query on that. Also, i cannot change the index structure. I can only perform queries or do some post processing after retrieving results. So anyone has any idea how to run this type of query, or even obtain my goal after getting results in the post processing? I am using Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope i fully understand what you are looking for.

I've managed to create a simple working example.

**Mappings**

Using `char_group` tokenizer:

> The char_group tokenizer breaks text into terms whenever it encounters a character which is in a defined set. It is mostly useful for cases where a simple custom tokenization is desired, and the overhead of use of the pattern tokenizer is not acceptable.

[Char Group Tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-chargroup-tokenizer.html)

```
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "char_group",
          "tokenize_on_chars": [
            "letter",
            "whitespace"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "text": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "digit": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Post a few documents**

```
PUT my_index/_doc/1
{
  "text": "This is a good thing for versions before 3.2 but bad for 3.5 and later"
}

PUT my_index/_doc/2
{
  "text": "This is a good thing for versions before 5 but bad for 6 and later"
}
```

**Search Query**

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "text.digit": {
        "gte": 3.2,
        "lte": 3.5
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Results**

```
"hits" : {
 "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "my_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "text" : "This is a good thing for versions before 3.2 but bad for 3.5 and later"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

**Another Search Query**

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "text.digit": {
        "gt": 3.5
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Results**

```
"hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "my_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "text" : "This is a good thing for versions before 5 but bad for 6 and later"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

**Analyze Query**

Play with the following query till you get the desired results.

It is already compatible to your example.

> This is a good thing for versions before 3.2 but bad for 3.5 and later

```
POST _analyze
{
  "tokenizer": {
    "type": "char_group",
    "tokenize_on_chars": [
      "letter",
      "whitespace"
    ]
  },
  "text": "This is a good thing for versions before 3.2 but bad for 3.5 and later"
}
```

Hope this helps